# Need to extract files into Pen drive based on the availability of Pen drives and files

Tags: batch-file

I have a script to download zipped files from a server and I wanted to extract the downloaded zipped files to the connected Pen drives. I used to run a batch file to delete early morning to delete the existing zip files.

Not all the zipped files will be present all the time after the download, sometimes only 2 files will be there, so based on the availability of zipped files and the connected pen drives I would like to extract the software.

Following are the possible flash drives and zipped file names:

Drives = F G H I J
downloaded_zipped_files=MHI_AH10,MPR_BH11,MPR_CH12,MHI_DH13,MPR_EH14,MHI_FH15,MHI_GH16,MBA_HH17

I had tried my best but could not make it. Help me if anyone knows how to solve this. I am adding my batch file code too.

Note : File names will be like MHI_AH10xxxxx and MPR_BH11xxxxx so I will use wildcard (*) to extract the specified file. If the first file in the list is not present then it should move on to next file and extract in the first pen drive, then it should move on to check for whether second pen drive is present or not.

This is not the full code, need to have logic to perform the above mentioned actions.

### Code:

```
set drive_list=F G H I J

set test_list[0]=MHI_AH10
set test_list[1]=MPR_BH11
set test_list[2]=MPR_CH12
set test_list[3]=MHI_DH13
set test_list[4]=MPR_EH14
set test_list[5]=MHI_FH15
set test_list[6]=MHI_GH16
set test_list[7]=MBA_HH17

(for %%b in (%drive_list%) do ( 

   if exist %%b: (
      if exist C:\Users\venkat\Documents\%test_list[0]%*.7z (
         7z x C:\Users\venkat\Documents\%test_list[0]%*.7z -o%%b:\
      )  
   )

))
```

Comment: Seems you need a `for /L` loop: `if exist %%b: for /l %%i in (0,1,7) do (` and replace the `0` in the following two lines to `%%i`. Don't forget the closing `)`.

Comment: Hi Stephan
I changed the script as per your suggestion, it extracts all .7z files in all the connected pen drives. But I expect to extract only specific file in a pen drive and if it is done, it should move on to next drive and look into next available 7z file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made changes to the drive_list as array as how test_list array is declared and used go to statements to break the execution once one file is extracted in a pen drive.

Following is the modified code:

```
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set drive_list[0]=E
set drive_list[1]=F
set drive_list[2]=G
set drive_list[3]=H
set drive_list[4]=I
set drive_list[5]=J
set drive_list[6]=K
set drive_list[7]=L

set test_list[0]=MHI_AH10
set test_list[1]=MPR_BH11
set test_list[2]=MPR_CH12
set test_list[3]=MHI_DH13
set test_list[4]=MPR_EH14
set test_list[5]=MHI_FH15
set test_list[6]=MHI_GH16
set test_list[7]=MBA_HH17

rem Initializing test_list array index
set /A test_list_array_index=0

rem Initializing Drive array index
set /A drive_array_index=0

:nextdriveloop
echo !test_list_array_index!

for %%b in (!drive_array_index!,1,5) do (
   
   echo Inside first for loop
   
   if exist !drive_list[%%b]!: (
      
      for /l %%i in (!test_list_array_index!,1,7) do ( 
         
         if exist C:\Users\venkat\Documents\!test_list[%%i]!*.7z (
 
            7z x C:\Users\venkat\Documents\!test_list[%%i]!*.7z -o!drive_list[%%b]!:\
            
            set /A "test_list_array_index=%%i + 1"
            set /A "drive_array_index=%%b + 1"
            
            goto :nextdriveloop
         
         )
        )

    )
  
)
```